# How can I reject a queryset object while serializing the data using a Django Rest ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a queryset that I'm trying to serialize with my `CasePartySerializer` which inherits the Django REST Framework `ModelSerializer` class. It has a nested serializer called `CaseRuleDocketSerializer`.

Here is how I instantiate it.

```py
def get_queryset(self):

    self.queryset = CaseParty.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

def get(self):
    serial = CasePartySerializer(
        list(
            self.queryset[
                self.offset:self.offset + self.limit
            ]
        ), 
        many=True, 
        context={
            'tracked': self.tracked.value,
            'request': self.request
        }
    )
```

Simple Enough, but what if I want to conditionally pass over and reject objects so they are not included in the finalized `serial.data`.

I'm sure there is probably some exception I can raise that would pass over this database object, but I'm unsure what that would be. I looked through the documentation without any luck; it's something that surprised me considering the quality of the REST Framework documentation. I'm probably missing something simple.

Here is my `CasePartySerializer` so you can see my conditionals. In this example you can see they are based on results from the nested serializer `CaseRuleDocketSerializer` output which is not available from the `get_queryset` method. If one of the ruledocket items is 'red' it does not need to be included in the serializer result. I know I can filter in the `get_queryset` method also, but it just seems it would be easier to do in the serializer itself.

```py
class CaseRuleDocketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    table_row_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = CaseRuleDocket
        fields = [
            'unique_id',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
            'date_time',
            'entry',
            'party'
        ]

    def get_is_user_only_created(self, obj):

        if obj.is_user_created and not obj.is_court_created:
            return 'green' 
        elif obj.is_court_created and not obj.is_user_created:
            return 'blue'
        else:
            return 'red'

class CasePartySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    docket_of_party = CaseRuleDocketSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    table_row_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CaseParty
        fields = [
            'is_tracked',
            'created_date',
            'updated_date',
            'serve_status',
            'serve_status_date',
            'defendant',
            'plaintiff',
            # CONTINUE WITH THE REST OF THE FIELDS....
        ]

    def get_table_row_color(self, obj):

        errors = [
            x.table_row_color for x in self.obj.docket_party
        ]

        if 'blue' in errors:
            return 'blue'
        elif 'green' in errors:
            return 'green'
        else:
            # HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO EXCEPT AND REMOVE 
            # THIS CaseParty OBJECT INSTANCE
```

I have been using stackoverflow for many years and I have always found the answers I have needed when looking. For some reason I could not find a way to frame the question correctly. Also, I am familiar with the documentation and have read it thoroughly. If it is not suggested to filter inside of the queryset due to efficiency, readability, or some other missight on my part, please include the reason in your answer.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: The query should happen in the view... Can you add it? I am pretty sure there is some way to do it there with an exclude or filter statement.

Comment: Yes, in this example I can absolutely filter or exclude the queryset in the view, but in more dynamic serializers I have had the need to filter or exclude based on the results from a nested serializer inside of the parent. Maybe I need to try searching with this language. Also, I could just look at the ```ModelSerializer``` base class code and search for a method that could be overridden to add this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, where you are filtering all `CaseParty` instances that have no related `CaseTrack` models, your best bet would be to update the view's `get_queryset` method.

Basically, rather than using `queryset = CaseParty.objects.all()`, you could write your own `get_queryset(self)` method, which will filter out the unwanted models.

To give a more concrete example:

```py
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        # We fetch all party instances
        party_instances = CaseParty.objects.all()
        # We fetch all case_tracks linked to them
        case_tracks = CaseTrack.objects.get(
                user=self.request.user, 
                case__in=party_instances
            )
        # We extract the party ids from case tracks
        party_ids_from_casetracks = {item.case.id for item in case_tracks}
        # We only keep those parties in the queryset
        party_instances_with_tracks = [item for item in party_instances if item.id in party_ids_from_casetracks ]
        return party_instances_with_tracks
```

You'll find more example in [the official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user)

If filterting at the viewset level is problematic because different endpoints/views must have different filters, then simply filter then from within the view action.

As someone else mentionned in the comments, the serializer is not here to filter the data:

- The view filters the data (queryset, get_queryset, filter_queryset, detail view, etc)
- The serializer receives the data, validates it, create/update/destroy instances, return representation and internal values

Comment: I guess I should have avoided a generic analogous representation of my problem.

Comment: As noted in my question, my problem can't be fixed in the ```get_queryset``` method of which I'm using. The conditionals required for filtering the queryset are the result of a nested serializer which is not accessible from that method but inside the serializer itself . I will update the question with a less general example later on today.